# Datagridview to list parent record and last child record only

Tags: c#, sql, tableadapter

I have two tables - t1 and t2.
I am trying to fill a datagridview with the company (t1) and last contract signed (t2).

I am using an accdb with OLE connection in visual studio 2019.

I have [t1].[ID] one-to-many linked to [t2].[t1ID].

I have just tried `select * from (t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = (MAX (t1ID) FROM t2 WHERE t2.t1ID = t1.ID)`

This is giving me error in WHERE clause and unable to parse query text.

I am entering this into the Dataset TableAdapter query in visual studio 2019.

I would like to get just one result:

company1       Contract 2020

I currently getting:

company1       Contract 2018

company1       Contract 2019

company1       Contract 2020

I have now tried

```
(Client t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     Contract t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ClientID AND t2.ID =
                         (SELECT        MAX(t2.ID) AS Expr1
                           FROM            t2
                           WHERE        (t1.ID = t2.ClientID)))
```

I now have syntax error

Comment: Is it WinForms app? Add tag. | What do you use as a data source: a DataSet or a typed collection of classes?

Comment: I have just tried the following filter to the dataset, but it did not work.  WHERE Client.ID=Contract.ClientID and Contract.ID = MAX(ID)

Comment: So your question is about how to write an sql query?

Comment: I am using a accdb file with oledb connection in visual studio 2019

Comment: I think you need to remove the `winforms`, `datagridview`, and `bindingsource` tags, add the `sql` tag, and edit the question body by putting your attempts to write the sql query there.

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax error is in the last sub query FROM t2 should be 'Contract t2'

SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM            (Client t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
Contract t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ClientID)
WHERE        (t2.ID =
(SELECT        MAX(ID) AS Expr1
FROM            Contract t2
WHERE        (t1.ID = ClientID)))